# Eclipse Open With option

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I want to open a .xml file in a web browser and my colleagues who have the same drop that I have are able to right click the file and select **open with** option.  My drop does not give me that option. What do I need to do to get that option?

Comment: What is "drop"?

Comment: Open With is not shown at all if there is no way to open the file using any editor. What does the Resource tab of the Properties show for this?

Comment: Is there a way to add an attachment into this comment?  That way I can show you what the issue is.